# Error after login to Magento on core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php on line 437

Tags: magento, error

None of out programmers has changed anything to the code, but out of nothing now, when a user tries to login on the backend, we have this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object in
>   /home/r1tech/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/User.php on
>   line 437

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: When does that error appear?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that... it is when the user tries to login on the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a real Magento problem.

Somehow the files got corrupted. I re-uploaded everything and now it works just fine.